# How to open image in default image viewer, using VB.Net?

Tags: vb.net

Please help me to execute the default image viewer when i pass the path of the image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Process.Start

See: http://visualbasic.about.com/od/usingvbnet/a/prstrt.htm

Comment: Tnx alot it worked when i pass path of a txt file. But when pass image path to                                      ProcessProperties.Arguments = "C:\Users\minsara\Desktop\Final\My Project\cloudcomputing.jpg"                                                   what should be the ProcessProperties.FileName = ????                 i tries using "Windows Photo Viewer", bt it didnt work. Can you please help me.

Comment: Tnx alot for your quick replies it worked, when i pass the path of the application exe.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for `Process.Start`, which does exactly that.

Comment: Hw do i fill the ProcessProperties.FileName , when i need to open image using default photo viewer.

Comment: Tnx alot for your quick replies it worked, when i pass the path of the application exe.

Comment: Tnx alot for your quick replies it worked, when i pass the path of the application exe.

Comment: @kevin: No; you should just call `Process.Start(filename)`, where `filename` is the path to an image (or any other file).  Windows will open it in the default viewer.